# Spring boot not recognizing class outside boot class package

Tags: spring-boot

I just started to learn Spring boot and I am wondering about a behavior I see.

I have just two classes. 1. Spring boot class 2. Controller class.

Please refer the images. It all works fine when I keep bot the classes inside the main package. But it doesn't work if I move the GreetingController class to the rest folder. I am getting 404 If I do that. Why is this?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To work you have to put your controller on same folder or sub folder of BootStarter. 
The reason is that Spring Boot scan all classes of his folder and subfolder.

Comment: Thanks. So if I want to put classes into different packages. Should each package then have one class annotated with @SpringBootApplication?

Comment: The convention is one SpringBootApplication per application. You have to put it in the folder upper if you want.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I thought. Really appreciate the help.

Comment: You can actually put it in a different package as well, but then you'll have to add some `@ComponentScan`'s by yourself.